# 404 page not found when migrate traefik from command args to config file

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I am migrate the traefik from command args to config file, this is the legacy config in kubenertes deployment look like:

```
containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:2.10.4
          args:
            - '--global.checknewversion'
            - '--global.sendanonymoususage'
            - '--entryPoints.metrics.address=:9300/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.web.address=:8000/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp'
            - '--api.dashboard=true'
            - '--ping=true'
            - '--metrics.prometheus=true'
            - '--metrics.prometheus.entrypoint=metrics'
            - '--providers.kubernetescrd'
            - '--providers.kubernetesingress'
```

after migrate to config file, the config file look like:

```
authSources:
  jwtSource:
    jwt:
      signingSecret: super-secret
      
ping: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":8000"
  websecure:
    address: ":8443"
  traefik:
    address: ":9000"
  metrics:
    address: ":9300"
```

now I am facing the issue that, all the legacy website shows `404 page not found` error(I did not change the ingress route config, the legacy ingress route config works fine). Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?